# How to align elements in a vuetify3 block button to the sides?

Tags: vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

Let's say I have the following button:

```
<v-btn block size="x-large">
    <v-btn icon size="small" variant="contained">
        <v-icon>mdi-information</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    Button Text
    <v-icon>mdi-check</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

The icons on the left and right are clamped together with the text. How do I put them on the right and left edge of the button, respectively? I've tried using `v-spacer`s, but it didn't work. I also tried using a `v-row` in the button, but to no avail as the items became even more misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

You can horizontally align the items using the `justify` property.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify()  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.10/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.10/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-btn block size="x-large">
      <v-row justify="space-between">
        <v-col md="4">
          <v-btn icon size="small" variant="contained">
            <v-icon>mdi-information</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-col>
        <v-col>Button Text</v-col>
        <v-col md="4">
          <v-btn icon size="small" variant="contained">
            <v-icon>mdi-check</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-btn>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: This example uses Vuetify 2, while I am using Vuetify 3. In my case, it looks all messed up. I can show a screenshot: [Screenshot on Lightshot](https://prnt.sc/TXHmFlOa6prY)